# Question and Answer text areas remain blank even as the preview updates with what I typed (Win 10, Firefox 92.0.1) (fixed in FF 93.0?)

Tags: bug, questions, answers, user-interface

I cannot see what I am typing right now:

[image]

Bizarrely, after adding that image I have some “bad character” boxes:
[image]

This is on Windows 10, Firefox 92.0.1

Comment boxes are fine. Other text areas on other sites are also fine. This behavior is new since yesterday. I have not updated my browser (or anything else) in the interim, to my knowledge.

Comment: Would you mind to accept your answer to show that the issue resolved? :)

Comment: @Akixkisu Since it affected only this site, I’m not convinced there wasn’t some bug with the site, even if newer versions of FF avoid it. I’d rather leave it open in case someone from SE comes by and knows what was up.

Answer (score 4):

When I checked my version of Firefox, I noticed that it offered to restart to update. After doing so (now 93.0), the bug appears to be gone. Still bizarre that it was only this site and no other.

Comment: It's obviously related to the D&D 5e Simulacrum/Wish bug. 

Comment: How many other sites are you entering data in multi-line textboxes? It appears the issue with Firefox was just with those - the rest of the page seems fine from your screenshots.

Comment: @DaleM I tried Wikipedia.